# C++ not waiting for an input

Tags: c++

so I have been learning C++ and was working on a monkey see monkey do program and i managed to get the first input working but the second input it just skips straight over it, i have no clue why and any help would be apreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char monkey_1;
char monkey_2;

int msmd()
{
    cout << "monkey one:"; cout << endl;
    cin >> monkey_1;
    system("cls");
    cout << "monkey two:"; cout << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> monkey_2;
    cout << "waiting"; cout << endl;
    if (monkey_1 == monkey_2)
    {
        cout << "both monkeys are happy."; cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "the monkeys are upest."; cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    msmd();
}
```

Comment: What input are you typing?  (You don't need `cin.clear()` BTW - that clears any error conditions on the `cin` stream, and there's no reason to think you'd have any.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a monkey see++ monkey do program?

Comment: micronag: The C++ Standard requires `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Are you giving more than one characters as input when it is asking for the first time? If yes, then it will not ask for the input the second time as the buffer of `cin` already has characters available. The next character that you typed will get assigned to monkey_2.

Comment: (More specifically, I'll point out that `char` accepts a single character, and `>>` skip whitespace, so if you've typed something like "jump" and pressed ENTER, it'll read `j` into `monkey_1` and `u` into `monkey_2` without waiting for more text or another press of ENTER.  Same if you typed `j` `SPACE` `u` `ENTER`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you intent to only get a single character from the input as the monkeys are of type `char`? If not, change them to `string`, otherwise it will only assign a single character per `cin`.

If you want to input a sentence, `cin` also splits on spaces, so if you enter "something else", the first `cin` will assign `something` to monkey_1, and the second `cin` will automatically assign `else` to monkey_2.
To get around this you can use `getLine(cin,monkey_x)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two point needs to be modified.

1. char monkey_1 and mokeny_2 should be declared as string for get more than 1 character.
2. void main need to be changed as int main.

Comment: Why would it be a problem for the `monkey` variables to be `char`?

Comment: Because there was no assumption monkey is just 1 character. :) With original code, if puts some characters as input, then it will be given to 2nd's monkey.

Comment: There's always assumptions about inputs - especially if you're trying to simplify so you remove sanitisation. It's a beginner problem, so having monkey `A` and monkey `B` seems like a simple and plausible problem. To me it's not obvious that using `char` is wrong, so I wouldn't assume that the OP "needs to [modify]" them.